# Move android components in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-activity, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have an **Activity** which has an **EditText** programmatically added to a **LinearLayout** inside a **ScrollView**.

```
ScrollView <- LinearLayout <- EditText(s)
```

Is possible to rearrange their position by seting X and Y axis or something as Swing does for Components?

This is my code:

```
for (Field classField : todoFields) {

    CustomEditText field = new CustomEditText(this);

    field.setName(classField.getName());

    layoutFieldWrapper.addView(field);

}
```

EDIT:

Can I freely move components around the interface, for instance: Put component next to another by setting the same Y and different X or overlap any of them to other, ecc.. does it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout`. Replace it with your `LinearLayout` inside your `ScrollView`. This layout gives you much accessibility. You can move your views in your user interface freely using this type of layout. You will have to play around with some attributes and try like: gravity, layout_centerVertical, padding, layout_margin, layout_width, layout_height, layout_below, layout_toRightOf, and a lot more...

Reference Link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right then you can call the method with index parameter like this:

```
layoutFieldWrapper.addView(field, index);
```

Hope this is the right suggestion or hint.

Comment: Thankyou! This was one apreciated and useful hint. I wish to know also if I can freely move components around the interface, for instance: Put component next to another by setting the same Y and different X or overlap any of them to other, ecc.. does it's possible?